# WindowManager android 5.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-windowmanager

I'm having an issue regards display a `WindowManager` in Android 5.1, in Android 5.0 this issue doesn't present, but today when tested on Nexus 5 running the latest Android 5.1 i got this exception below

```
    android.view.WindowManager$InvalidDisplayException: Unable to add window   
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@27217ee5 -- the specified window type is not valid
```

pointing to the `WindowManager.addView(params,view);`

any suggestions about what changes in android 5.1 to cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also got such errors.
But I fixed with this way.

```
 Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

 int width = display.getWidth();

 int height = display.getHeight();

 dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
```